# The emulator process for AVD has terminated. Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I have downloaded android studio and when i try to use any virtual device it shows this [error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWRx4.png)

I have check the logs to identify the problem and it shows this problem.

```
WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819
INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 34 - [4768:8220:20240305,164829.503:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\SUFYAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.1.18.db\attachments\6a0857ae-9c2b-4bf6-95ae-d5108fce41f1: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried redownloading emulator and even the android studio itself. Downloaded android sdk again but still facing this issue.
please help me as I am a beginner and i dont know much. i have searched youtube and google very much about it but haven't found any solution which makes me think that i am the only person facing this issue.

Comment: FYI `-1073741819` will be `C0000005` in hex, in case you want to look further

Comment: can u please explain?

Comment: I am saying that what AS shows in log as decimal value `-1073741819` makes more sense when you see it in hex as usually this is how it gets defined in the source code etc. It is probably how it should be shown but for some reasons they did not apply proper formatting. Might be useful while searching for similar issues over the net